# Why wavelength does not change in scattering?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, visible-light, waves

In Compton effect, the photon is scattered by a free electron and it loses energy and thereby changes wavelength.

1. However, in Rayleigh scattering, the light is scattered in different directions although the wavelength remains the same. Obviously, when the light is scattered in Rayleigh scattering, the energy content of the light beam surely decreases but the wavelength of light does not change. Why?
2. Rayleigh scattering dominates in classical phenomena while Compton effect is predominant in quantum phenomena.But how does the dual nature of light accomodate for this by showing its particle nature in Compton effect and wave nature in Rayleigh scattering?

Comment: "energy content of the light beam surely decreases but the wavelength of light does not change"
This is a contradiction. Either Rayleigh scattering doesn't change it at all, or it is significantly less energy loss than the Compton effect (so that this comparison makes sense)

Comment: @Lacklub That is the problem. The light is scattered in all directions (check any book), so energy must decrease but the unique distinguishing feature of Rayleigh scattering is that the scattered light has same wavelength as incident light.

Comment: When light is scattered in all directions, that is having something like 100 incident (coherent) photons, which each get sent in a different direction. Each photon has the same energy before and after.

Comment: To clarify your point (1) are you saying Rayleigh scattering causes the intensity of the unscattered beam to decrease? I ask because beam intensity is just the number of photons per second and is unrelated to wavelength.

Comment: @JohnRennie No. I am talking of the decrease in energy of scattered light photons in Rayleigh scattering.

Comment: OK then I don't understand why you say this scattering must be inelastic.

Comment: @JohnRennie My question is: in Compton effect, the photons are scattered in different directions and it changes wavelength but in Rayleigh scattering, the photons when scattered, show no change in wavelength. Why is this contradiction?

Comment: Ah, that's because $\Delta\lambda\propto 1/m$ where $m$ is the mass of the thing doing the scattering. Air molecules are a lot heavier than electrons.