# Does blue light scattered from air molecules transmit them kinetic energy affecting their temperature?

Tags: energy, temperature, scattering, atmospheric-science

If it cannot ionize them does blue light scattered from air molecules transmit them part of its kinetic energy so that their temperature increases? If scattering is weak in upper atmosphere, are there, because of that, no air molecules with high kinetic energy so the temperature is lower?

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279199/why-wavelength-does-not-change-in-scattering)

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Maybe light once scatters from an aproaching molecule and in another case from a receiding one so the mean value is as it is an elastic scattering?

Comment: Not sure, but if inverse scattering would happen with same probability to normal scattering - we would no see sky blue. I bet it's more related that molecule momentum is too big compared to photon, so it can't affect molecule much. Btw, Compton has noticed scattering of very energetic X-rays on very light particles - electrons. So it has to do with momentum proportions of interacting particles.

Answer (score 2):

Rayleigh scattering is an elastic process, hence leaves the average kinetic energy of the scattering particles untouched.
Raman scattering, which happens coincidentally in Earth's atmoshphere with R. scattering, has an influence on the rotational energies of molecules.
Rotational energies are however, in the far-infrared, while atmospheric temperature on this planet corresponds to infrared energies, hence the change in energies due to Raman scattering is about $m_{proton}/m_{H_2O}$ or $m_{proton}/m_{N_2}$. Hence, in principle Raman scattering is able to change the scatterers temperature, but I am not sure the sunlight is intense enough for this effect to be noticeable.